# UITableView displays briefly in narrow orientation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a pretty straightforward UITableView in an iOS app that loads its data from a server, but whenever it displays, it briefly displays at about 2/3 the width before correcting to the right width.  I've noticed that it's always the second section (of two) but I don't know how to fix it.  I managed to catch a screen shot of the brief display:

[image: This displays for a second or two before the proper screen displays]

Here is what it looks like after it fixes itself:

[image: After it fixes itself]

I've tried a lot of things but can't figure out what's causing this.  I don't think the UITableView did this in the beginning of the app's life, but it has been really consistent for some weeks now.  Any thoughts/help are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have custom cell or share you code from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: you want the UITableView line fully to your view?

Comment: It is not a custom cell.  I dequeue a cell that is built in Storyboard, and it displays fine after the view refreshes.  And yes, I want the second view of my two screen shots, which I have, but in between, every time the view reloads, I get the narrower view first, sometimes for 2-3 seconds, then it redraws correctly.

Comment: I've tried changing from two sections to one, and various other things, to no avail.

Comment: Still can't figure this out.  I have a clue: if I enable the "Edit" button and click it, the UITableView goes into this [narrow] mode and stays there until I end edit mode, segue to the downstream view, and come back.  So it seems to have something to do with editing, though I am not even using editing yet, and the methods do very little or nothing.  I've tried various things to change the edit response, but the list still draws narrow.  Perplexing.

Comment: do you use Autolayout or old good frames ?

Comment: @Max, The Autolayout box is checked, but I've tried it both ways and it doesn't seem to make any difference.  It does seem like an autolayout kind of issue, something that is competing to resize the list, but I can't figure out how to control it, or defeat it.

Comment: @GlennReid, run with Instruments and see if you block UI thread significantly for any reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this, with some help from a friend at Apple.

The problem was that I had inadvertently connected the tableView to the titleView in Interface Builder, which caused it to think it was drawing in the title area at least some of the time.

When I dragged the connection for the tableView, the first time I accidentally chose "titleView" instead of "tableView".  I dragged the connection again, and chose the correct "tableView" the second time.

What I did not know at the time, and took me a while to discover, is that somewhere along the way, Interface Builder started to allow multiple outlets for the same control.  I assumed that by dragging the connection a second time, it overwrote the first.  Not true.  Both of the connections were still there, one of them quite the troublemaker.

Disconnecting the table view from the "titleView" outlet solved the problem.  I sincerely hope nobody ever runs into this, because it's difficult to diagnose and fix!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Comment: Thanks; just tried that, and it removed the inset (slightly) from the edge of the "good" view, but didn't solve the underlying problem of the intermediate much narrower view.  It's perplexing.  I've been going through the whole view controller, method by method, commenting things out, modifying things, to no avail.